# Accessing an alternative Azure domain / portal as a co-admin

Tags: azure

A customer added me as a co-admin so I can manage their account (deploy our product, etc.).

I need to access their portal UI, but I don't see a way to get there after I am logged on to Azure. Even if I manually change the last part of the URL (the organisation domain), I get thrown back to the point of origin.

How do I get there?

Comment: What did Azure support say?

Comment: I am still waiting for their reply. The guy seems to think I need to be taught how to access the portal, so he sent me a link to the portal. I feel like banging my head on the wall.

Comment: In my experience contacting Azure support is just a big waste of time. The support has a lot of problems to understand even a simple problem descriptions. Azure is a help yourself platform.

Comment: Well, I found the Shanghai support very helpful, but the others are really a waste of time, like you say. But that's a bit off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it's been resolved. I'm posting it in case someone else is tangled here.

Basically, it turns out that once you are added as a co-admin, you will see the other subscription as a choice.

Another thing I was not aware of, is that you may have two logins under for the same email account: one of them is organisational, while the other one is "Microsoft account" (personal). In my case, I never used the personal one.

The support told me to log on using the personal account because apparently the customer set up his subscription as personal and not organizational. I tried, and it kicked me out. I mis-interpreted the reason as that I had no personal account. I told them that, and got silence on the other end.

After kicking and screaming for a few days, the request was escalated and the technical support told me that there are two accounts in disguise, and my personal account may have a different password. I reset the password in the personal account, logged on, and easily got the access to the customer's subscription.

Answer (score 2):

I assume your customer is using [organizational](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sign-up-organization/) Azure account.

You don't tell if you are using a Microsoft account or an account created by your customer but that should make no difference.

You go to Azure portal using either:

- https://manage.windowsazure.com/
- https://manage.windowsazure.com/ORGANIZATION_DOMAIN where <ORGANIZATION_DOMAIN> is the domain set up by your customer likely something as <COMPANY>.onmicrosoft.com

Log in with your account. If that doesn't work your customer has failed the account setup.

The only possible problem I can see is that your customer hasn't assigned you as an administrator as it requires an extra step:

1. First your client have to add your account to their organization's Active Directory.
2. Second your client have to grant you administrator rights to each Azure subscription. In (today's version of) management portal it is 1) select Settings from left-hand side vertical toolbar then 2) Administrators from top menu.

Your customer probably did #1 but not #2.

Comment: Wow you rock. The onmicrosoft.com did the trick! But I am still getting the error message "None of your subscriptions are associated with this directory." I guess I'll ask them to follow the steps you mentioned, and follow it up here.